# Do moves that decrease stats (accuracy, defense, attack, & etc) stack?

Tags: pokemon-series

I was wondering if I use a move such as [Sand-Attack](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sand-Attack_%28move%29) repeatedly on an enemy will it keep on reducing it's accuracy or is there a point where it becomes ineffective to use?

Do moves that decrease accuracy, defense, attack, or a certain stat stack on top of each other?

[image: Bulbapedia Image]

Borrowed from [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sand-Attack_%28move%29#In_other_generations)'s Wiki page on Sand-Attack.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, stat modifying moves **do stack**. When the modifier reaches its **limit** (which does exist - **6 modifiers** up or down, or a max of 4 times or 0.25 times the original stat), the message upon trying to modify the stat again will be something along the lines of "Vulpix's attack won't go any lower!".

Comment: Wow, you beat me to it. I still remember the times where Metapod would harden until "its defense won't go up".

Comment: @Nolonar When I keep a close eye on the new questions section, that eye is close.